# How to match all alphanumeric except underscore on Python

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to match with regex all alphanumeric characters, except for the underscore.
I'm currently using `r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*"`, but I wondered if it was possible to use `\w` and exclude `_`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, like that: `[^\W_]`

Where `\W` is the opposite of `\w`