# Regex to match "no spaces or no symbols"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a password with "no spaces or no symbols" in javascript regex.

What I tried was: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]|(.*\s)/g`

I'm not sure if this is a correct regex. Can someone help please?

Comment: Your expression reads as "match a single non-alphanumeric character or match anything followed by whitespace." I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Please provide example strings and expected output.

Comment: Is [**`^(?:[^@!$\n]+|\S+)$`**](https://regex101.com/r/a0zzeR/1) what you're looking for?

Comment: @sumeetkumar That regular expressions reads as "At the beginning of the string, find zero or more alphanumeric characters and/or underscores. Then, find zero or more alphanumeric characters and/or underscores at the end of the string." As an expression, it's non-sensical.

Comment: @MikeC Actually, the [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ahhh, interesting. Good to know. Still, what they wrote is still non-sensical.

Comment: @MikeC Neither is the question in its current form. There is no sense matching a string that has no spaces, or a string that can be all spaces. It is the same as matching any string.

Comment: If you're unsure about the behavior of your regex, the best is to test it. There is some useful online tools to help you understand it like [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "symbol"?

Answer (score 2):

https://regex101.com/r/XKJcTs/1

```
^[^\W_]+$
```

Reject everything that is not alphanumeric and the underscore. Require at least once. This will allow passwords with one character. You can change the `+` to `{min, max}` or to `{min,}` for no upper limit.

```
 ^[^\W_]{3,48}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/XKJcTs/2

Taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23817519/2604378